# Gärtner-Ellis theorem on Markov chains

Tags: probability-theory, large-deviation-theory

Let $Z_n \in \mathcal{X}$ be a sequence of independent random variables where $\mathcal{X}$ is a topological vector space and let $\mu_n$ the probability measures associated with $Z_n$. Suppose that $Z_n$ that satisfies the conditions for the abstract Gärtner-Ellis Theorem. So the rate function $I(\cdot)$ associated with $Z_n$ is the Fenchel–Legendre transform of $M(\lambda) =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{n} \log E[\exp \langle n\lambda, Z_n \rangle ]$.

Now consider a second random variable $Y_n$ that is a Markov chain ($Y_n$ is sampled from $Y_{n-1}$) and the probability measure associated with $Y_n$ is $\mu_n$.

My question is:

Is $I(\cdot)$ the rate function associated with $Y_n$?

If answer is yes to the above question, let me provide a counter-example of the equivalence of the rate function of $Z_n$ and $Y_n$.

Consider two random variables on $\{0,1\}$
let $g_n$ be 1 with probability $1/2$, else 0
let $h_1$ = $g_1$ and then for $n>1$, let $h_n=1-h_{n-1}$ with probability
$(1/2)^n$ and else $h_n=h_{n-1}$.

Note that for all $n$, $h_n$ and $g_n$ have the same probability distribution,
$Prob(g_n = 1) = 1/2$ (by definition).
$$
Prob(h_n = 1) = Prob(h_{n-1}=1)\cdot(1/2)^n + Prob(h_{n-1}=0)\cdot(1-(1/2)^n) = (1/2) \cdot (1/2)^n+(1/2) \cdot (1-(1/2)^n) = (1/2)\cdot((1/2)^n + 1-(1/2)^n) = 1/2
$$
Hence $Prob(g_n=1) = Prob(h_n=1)$.

At the limit both random variables have the same distribution,
but the convergence of the sequences is rather different. ($h_n$
converges, $g_n$ doesn't)

My other question is: Does this example invalidate the positive answer to first question?

Comment: You really need to rephrase the paragraph "Now consider a second random variable $Y_n$ sampled from $Y_{n-1}$ such that the probability measures assoociate with $Y_n$ is $\mu_n$." At the moment, one cannot know what you mean by this.

Comment: Dear @Did, Is now the question more clear?.

Comment: It seems you are assuming that the distribution of $Z_n$ is $\mu_n$ for every $n$, that $(Z_n)$ satisfies a LDP with rate $I$, and that $(Y_n)$ is a Markov chain with marginal distributions $\mu_n$, and that you are asking whether, then, $(Y_n)$ also satisies a LDP with rate $I$. But this is trivially so since the LDP for $(Z_n)$ describes probabilities $P(Z_n\in B)$, likewise a LDP for $(Y_n)$ would describe probabilities $P(Y_n\in B)$, and you are assuming that for every $n$ and $B$, $P(Z_n\in B)=P(Y_n\in B)$...

Comment: Dear @Did yes, the answer could be trivial for an expert. However this equivalence can produces an example that at least for me it is counter-intuitive. I will add it to the question

Comment: In the example you added, $(h_n)$ and $g_n)$ both satisfy the same LDPs and fail the same LDPs. No counterexample at all.

Comment: What do you mean that $h_n$ and $g_n$ fail the same LDP?

Comment: If $(g_n)$ satisfies a given LDP, so does $(h_n)$. If $(g_n)$ fails a given LDP, so does $(h_n)$. If $(h_n)$ satisfies a given LDP, so does $(g_n)$. If $(h_n)$ fails a given LDP, so does $(g_n)$.

Comment: Dear @Did many thanks, your answers and comments have been very useful for me.

Comment: Cool. $ $ $ $ $ $